# How to add a field_key with default value when alert triggered?

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

How to add a `field_key` in influxdb measurement with default value?

If alert trigger in kapacitor then default value add in influxdb measurement.

Comment: what have you tries so far?

Comment: when email trigger then a 'true' value insert in default  field_key. so at last  count how many email trigger

Comment: Can you show some relevant code in the question?

Comment: sir has done my requirement by using pipeline.